# using path from registry in a batch file

Tags: batch, java, windows-registry

I am pretty new to registry and batch files editing.  I want to replace path `C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\bin` inside my batch file to a more generic path so that each time I don't have to modify the path and it automatically takes from the registry.

```
key path = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
inside key i have 
name = JavaHome
data = C:\Program Files\Java\jre8
```

Can someone help how to do it, or tell any reference documents to read?

Answer (score 3):

### [test.bat] file body

Batch file code which queries registry, gets parameter value into environment variable, then use this value for to get directory listing. Tested.

```
SetLocal
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v JavaHomePath') do set JavaHomePath=%%b
dir "%JavaHomePath%"
```

---

How does it works?

We use `REG` command-line utility for to obtain registry key value. According command is

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v JavaHome
```

Its output then will be parsed by `FOR /F` command. The command output looks like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
    JavaHome    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Java\jre8
```

When not specified then `<space/tab>` is used as a default delimiter. So 1st token is `Keyname`, 2nd is `KeyType` and 3th (and next, if value contains spaces) is `KeyValue`.

We specify `tokens=2*`. This (digit `2`) means that we want to assign 3rd token to specified variable (`%%a`) and (asterisk after the digit) all the tail to the auto-created variable with the name of the next (by alphabet) letter (i.e. `%%b`). So `KeyValue`, which is the tail after 2nd token and delimiter, will be placed into `%%b` variable.

And then we execute `set` command and assing this value to environment variable.

The `REG QUERY` produces 2 lines. `FOR` command porcesses each of them. So `JavaHomePath` environment variable is set/overrided each time the next line is processed, and the result of the last line parsing is stored in the variable after all lines processed and `FOR` execution finished. You can update the code and pipe `REG QUERY` output to `FIND` to get only one line.

---

**PS.** Yesterday I had used "tokens=3*" in the answer. Today I test it on another workstation with another OS language - "tokens=3*" works wrong and "tokens=2*" works correct. It is strange for me, I don't understand why (I have been too inattentive? maybe...), but it is a fact... Now the code above works correctly from a batch file.

So test your final code carefully.

Comment: This works just fine, but some explanation what it does would be more helpful than a quick one-liner. FOR /F with TOKENS is far from obvious for a batch file beginner.

Comment: Good job! You have my up vote.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akina for very quick response.

Comment: But i had some doubt. so should i use JavaHomePath (since JavaHomePath=%b) inplace of C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\bin" in inside my batch file ?

Comment: @yash Yes. Do not forget to wrap variable name with percent signs `%JavaHomePath%`, this will tell CMD that variable value must be used instead of a literal. Additionally - add `SetLocal` in front of yur batch or `JavaHomePath=` as a last line of it for to remove the variable which is not necessary outside the batch.

Comment: @Akina . while using for command above my path in batch file and when executing the build, i am getting error b is unexpected at this time

Comment: @yash If you use the above code in batch file then the percent sign must be doubled (`set JavaHomePath=%%b`).

Comment: @Akina for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Web Start\1.0.1" /v Home') do set JavaHomePath=%%b 
 
if exist %JavaHomePath% goto SETVMPATH
goto SETENVFORBUILD                                                                                             i am using this but still getting java is not recognized. please see the path in the question  description

Comment: @yash I have tested everything one more time. The answer edited - look and test. Enable echo (for whole batch or for some lines) and check that the variable value is correctly assigned and inserted into the commands.

Comment: @Akina yes the code is correct. however a little bug. The path in my batch file is PROGRA~2 (which is program filesx86 ), And the path we are referring is of Program files . i can't find that path in registry. is it possible to edit this variable javahomepath slightly to add x86 so that it looks C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8 ?

Comment: It is strange that the path in registry do not match the path in the filesystem... of course you can parse the variable using the same command `FOR /F` using `\` as a delimiter and re-join it back adding this substring... but I'd recommend to check the correctness the registry data and, maybe, restore valid key value.

Comment: Good explanation. You can avoid the extra line using `skip=2` in `for`, no need to use `find`. Use HKLM for brevity. Note that the `reg` command is missing from your code.