# slightly changing path used inside a batch file

Tags: windows, batch, java, windows-registry

Follow this please [using path from registry in a batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/1481448/using-path-from-registry-in-a-batch-file/1481463?noredirect=1#comment2234692_1481463)

Code:

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in (' REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Web Start\1.0.1" /v Home') do set JavaPath=%%b
```

Output:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin
```

Question:
Can we add x86 in this path such as it points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin` ?

i tried using

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=\J" %%a in ( %JavaPath% ) do set path_temp = %%b
```

But i get erro The system cannot find the file C:\Program.

Comment: `tokens=*` means "put the tail (which is the whole string because none separate token numbers specified) into variable %%a". `delims=\J` means that delimiter is both ``\`` char and `J` char (not `\J` substring!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [test.bat]

```
@echo off
setlocal
set JavaPath=C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin
echo Before: %JavaPath%
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=\" %%a in ("%JavaPath%") do set JavaPath=%%a\%%b (x86)\%%c
echo After:  %JavaPath%
```

I.e. we use `\` as a delimiter. So 1st token `C:` is set to variable `%%a`, `Program Files` to variable `%%b` and the tail `Java\jre8\bin` to variable `%%c`. Then we re-join them back adding both delimiters (they were removed during parsing) and `<space>(x86)` substring.